# How to show maximum 3 lines of content in a cell of a gridView vertically alligned?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view which generates content dynamically. As this grid is used in a page that is accessed mostly from Windows CE with Internet Explorer 7 it is very important the solution to be compatible with Ie7.

So - as the screen is pretty small we cannot show too much text. So we decided to show only maximum of 3 lines of text in a cell, if less it should be vertically aligned on middle. A table row will have fixed height of 41px;

I came to many solutions - but if it works the centering then won't work trimming and so on. Can anyone please help me on this?

Update1: I just found out that his has to work also in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to nest a block inside the cell ?

On the table cell : `vertical-align: middle; height: 41px;`

Then inside the cell, have a block element with a maximum height of 3 lines of text (you should play with that value) and an overflow hidden : `max-height: 35px; overflow: hidden;`

```
<td><div>TEXT</div></td>
```

You should be able to determine the proper height using the font-size and line-height or by testing a bit.

This way, only 3 lines of text are visible and the block element is still vertically centered in the cell.

Comment: Hi Simon, hm...this looks pretty simple solution. I haven't done really like this. Just tested and it works on Ie11 and simulate IE7. I will test tomorrow on real device which uses only IE7 and I will let you know - but I am too afraid that 'something won't work' - I've already spent 2 days on this issue :|

Comment: aah, wanted to ask: why did you suggested on inner div to set 35px and not 41px? just like that?

Comment: well Simon, your idea worked - also combined with fnostro's. Issue is that I have just found out today that my solution should work also on IE6 :| which doesn't issue is that it will show all text...

Answer (score 0):

I'm expanding on @Simon answer here

I've found one issue in that table rows tend to ignore css height values.  To force height I made `<td>` elements of `display:block` to enforce the 41px height rule by Alexa.
The upside is that it meets your requirements, the downside is that I don't know how that affect table rendering/behavior.

Also to enforce no more than 3 rows of text I had to set the `<div>` `line-height` to 1em and its `max-height` to 3em

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tr {
  height: 41px;
  max-height: 41px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
td {
  width: 33%;
}
td div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1em;
  max-height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut est sit amet ex scelerisque porttitor quis non nunc. Phasellus consectetur nunc eget erat pellentesque faucibus. Donec magna felis, scelerisque eget odio id, euismod mollis ligula.
        Nam maximus, eros id dapibus efficitur, nibh neque ultricies dui, eget elementum sapien ante eu massa. Aliquam malesuada velit vitae sagittis semper. Nam iaculis sagittis dignissim. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas consectetur mi a nisl dictum laoreet.
        Suspendisse est dui, aliquet non efficitur eget, imperdiet a odio. Praesent iaculis porttitor efficitur.</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hi, your line height in em suggestion helped me in adjusting Simon's solution - but now I just have to make it work in ie6, too - as I've found today - which it doesn't work yet

Comment: There you have a problem, `max-height` does not work in ie6. If you don't already know about it, please make use of [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) for browser compatibility issues. Also, for what it's worth, ie6 through ie9 are no longer supported by Microsoft and have passed or are approaching their "end of life", meaning they no longer even receive updates and security patches.  I understand it's a requirement, but consider that sometimes a case should be made against dead technology.